# Why is the scipy.sparse.csr_matrix not storing all the values being passed to it?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

So I am currently trying to store a large sparse dataset (4.9 million rows and 6000 columns) in the csr_format. The dense format causes a memory error so I am loading it in line by line from a tsv file.
Here is how I do that:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
rows=np.empty(4865518,dtype=np.int16)
cols=np.empty(165050535,dtype=np.int16)
values=np.empty(165050535,dtype=np.int16)
labels=np.empty(4865517,dtype=np.int8)
file=open(r'HI-union-allFeatures\HI-union-allFeatures-nonZero-train0.tsv','r')
count=0
nnz=0
col_count=0
for l in file:
    if count>0:
        l=l.strip().split("\t")
        line=l[2:-1]
        labels[count-1]=l[-1]
        for pair in line:
            pair=pair.split()
            cols[col_count]=pair[0]
            cols[col_count]-=3
            values[col_count]=pair[1]
            col_count+=1
        nnz+=len(line)
        rows[count]=nnz        
    count+=1
cols.astype(np.int16,copy=False) #cols gets stored as 32 bit for some reason.
cols.shape #(165050535,)
rows.shape #(4865518,)
values.shape #(165050535,)
data=csr_matrix((values, cols, rows),copy=False)
data.nnz #30887
data.data.shape #should match values.shape but output is (30887,)
data.indices.shape #should match cols.shape but output is (30887,)
data.indptr.shape #matches rows.shape (4865518,)
```

However after creating the csr_matrix, it just elminates some of the values. I dont understand why. Here is the screenshot showing that data.data.shape does not match values.shape. I also verified the data in the orginal rows, cols and values arrays and they represent the data perfectly so I dont understand this behaviour. My pc is not running out of memory, I have 16gb of ram and this program barely takes up 1 GB. EDIT : This is my first question here so I'm sorry if I didnt post it correctly. Any help would be great.
[Link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv7T3.png)

Comment: Can you give a bit more information on the structure of the tsv file? How is the data represented? What type of values are in the data file?

Comment: With sizes like 165050535 and data taken from a file, we can't reproduce or diagnose your problem.  One thing you might check  is whether `values` has 0s, and whether those have been eliminated in `data.data`.

Comment: We prefer to see program results in a copy-n-paste rather than screen shot.  In this case the screen shot isn't too big.  Still it's a pain to switch back and forth between this tab and the one showing the shot.

Comment: rows(0) is never filled and could be anything. I'm surprised this worked at all.

Comment: Sorry just saw all these comments. The tsv file is stored as a pair of (column number, value). All values are integers and can be capped at 16 bits. This is an example row from the file:
2858 3 3806 1 4527 1
The number 165050535 is the number of non-zero entries in the file which need to be stored in the values array. No zeroes are present. I have edited it to show the copy and paste format. I tried filling rows[0] and had the same output. Also when I ask for the value of rows[0] it gives me a zero.

Comment: @MYousefi sorry didnt tag you in the reply.

Comment: @CJR rows[0] just returns a value of zero.

Comment: Sparse `indptr` and `indices` will be `np.int32` or even `np.int64` for larger matrices.  Using `int16` for these does not save you anything.  `int16` may be ok for the data array.  If you defined `rows`, `cols` and `values` correctly the elements should match respective `data` attributes, not just in `shape` but also in value.  Did you test any of this on smaller data sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.empty doesn't initialize arrays to zero. The value of rows[0] could be anything.

> empty, unlike zeros, does not set the array values to zero, and may therefore be marginally faster. On the other hand, it requires the user to manually set all the values in the array, and should be used with caution

Int16 has a maximum value of 32767. Your row pointers have a maximum value of 165 million. This is why your data is now smaller than an int16.

Both of these things are huge problems. Without example data, providing a working fix as an answer is not possible.

Comment: proper `indices` and `indptr` arrays are `np.int32` (or even `int64` for large matrices).

Comment: @CJR thank you. Removing the dtype value allowed the array to be bigger.